# Google USB Coral TPU installation - unable to install PyCoral library

Tags: tpu, google-coral

Environment:
Ubuntu 20.04,
Coral TPU USB accelerator

I'm following [these instructions](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/) - I was able to install the TPU Runtime after some Googling around unsigned package errors. However, when I try to add the PyCoral library I get errors around unmet dependencies. Can anyone help me with exact steps to resolve? Thanks. Also - my plan is to use the Edge TPU to run with Frigate inside a Docker Container. Do I need the PyCoral library for that? I'm a bit of a newb with Linux/Coral so I apologize if this answer should be obvious.

```
#sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pycoral : Depends: python3-tflite-runtime (= 2.5.0.post1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.10) but 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same issue running Ubuntu 22.04. Seems to be a conflict in the python versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Frigate:**

According to
https://docs.frigate.video/installation

the docker file includes the support of the Google Coral “out of the box”.

But you may need to consider these 2 statements:

> Frigate runs best with docker installed on bare metal debian-based distributions.

> Windows is not officially supported, but some users have had success getting it to run under WSL or Virtualbox. Getting the GPU and/or Coral devices properly passed to Frigate may be difficult or impossible. Search previous discussions or issues for help.

That means Docker on Windows (that uses the WSL) might not work properly. This is due to the difficulties e.g. to pass through USB devices from Windows to WSL, although there is hope:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/

Comment: The **PyCoral library** runs with **Python 3.6-3.9** You may want to check the version installed on your OS and may change it if needed. You may also consider to setup different Python environments.